# Where to put and how to read txt file

Tags: css, codenameone

I am passing an app to CSS and I have not been able to read a flat file that I am using.

In the figure I show where I had it at the beginning and the folder where I placed it in the "maven" version.

What is the correct way and if it is necessary to change the CSS?
[image]

My Method:

```
    public ListModel tomarDatosLocalizacion() {

    Vector aL = new Vector();
    try {
        aL = leeArchivo("/localidades.txt");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Dialog.show(idioma.getError(), ex.getMessage(), idioma.getContinuar(), null);
    }

    ListModel localidad = new DefaultListModel(aL);
    return localidad;
}

// Rutina que lee el archivo de subzonas en Texto y carga tabla de datos
private Vector leeArchivo(String nombreArchivo) throws IOException {
    InputStream lectura = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), nombreArchivo);
    String registro = null;
    Vector datos = new Vector();
    // Lee una un registro desde del archivo. null representa el EOF.
    while ((registro = leeRegistro(lectura)) != null) {
        Vector tmp = dividirCadena(registro, ",");
        datos.addElement(new Localidades(Integer.parseInt(tmp.elementAt(0).toString()), tmp.elementAt(1).toString(), tmp.elementAt(2).toString()));
    }
    lectura.close();
    return datos;
}
```

Comment: @Rob this makes sense for Codename One developers

Comment: Switch to file view in the IDE. It looks like you placed the resources in the root of the common project. They should be in a directory next to the java directory called resources.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Common project. Under the source hierarchy you can create a `resources` directory which is a special case in Maven. In it you can place arbitrary files and they will behave in the way you expect.